# Can a company receive a payment and never provide the paid service?

Tags: contract-law, terms-of-service, online, italy

I was wondering a question about a situation I'm involved in.
 Prefacing that I live in Italy, where an [European directive](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/consumers/shopping/guarantees-returns/index_en.htm) states that every customer in their territories must have legal rights to return any item or service in his ownership and receive complete refunds (except like shipping fees where previously specified) within 14 days; is it possible for an online service provider (specifically a VPS hosting provider), to have a "no-refund" policy AND a "You agree that we can terminate at our discreption your service for any reason without prior notice" policy in their ToS?
 I literally mean paying for receiving nothing because at their discreption I was "rude" asking why the setup page of the VPS I bought didn't check for an OS selection and when they asked me that selection I requested a refund because I considered and told them they were a non-serious company, and only for that, not even they deleted my order before it was even completed nor provided, but terminated my account on their site too.
 Can anyone give me any advice of any action (legal too if necessary) to undertake towards this company? 
 Thanks! 
 PS: Sorry for my english if it isn't 100% correct or well-written but as I said I live in Italy where english is not the first spoken nor written language even if I'm still learning it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### They must give you a refund

By saying they don't give refunds that are required by law they are engaging in misleading and deceptive conduct which will expose them to some serious fines. Report them to the relevant Italian authority.

Presumably, you paid for this service with a credit/debit card. Contact your card provider and dispute the transaction - they will put the money back in your account and that will probably the last you hear of this company.